# Pass diferent $_SESSION variable through <a> tag PHP

Tags: php, session, global-variables

Hello how can I pass a different $_SESSION variable depending on which link I clicked? For example something like this.

```
<a href="page2.php value="<?php echo $_SESSION['variable'] = "Foo" ?>Foo</a>
<a href="page2.php value="<?php echo $_SESSION['variable'] = "Bar" ?>Bar</a>
```

And in page2.php receive the correct value.
How can I do this without using $_POST or $_GET? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"How can I do this without using $_POST or $_GET?"* - `href` can only use GET not POST. If you want POST, you need to use inputs with a post method. You can use `file.php?var=X` in href and retrieve it with a GET array on the second page/subsequent pag(s).

Comment: why can't you do it with `$_POST` or `$_GET` ?

Comment: Do you want to set `$_SESSION['variable']` to `Foo` if the first link was clicked and to `Bar` if the second one was clicked?

Comment: @PedroLobito Because I dont want to use form and I also don't wanna pass the variables through the url :/

Comment: @Sebastian Yes exactly that. Is there a way to do it without using $_GET or $_POST?

Comment: You *don't* need to pass session variables. If the session is running - and it should be - then all session variables should be available.

Comment: A variable in a url doesn't need a form,  I think you misunderstood the concept of `$_SESSION`

Comment: @PedroLobito I know I don't need a form to use $_GET :/

Comment: @Madtin: Well no: Your session is on the server side, the link is at the client. You can trigger an update with ajax to change the session if you do not want to refresh the page

Comment: @Madtin You seem to know a lot, GL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only this way (but you need send variable to server, because SESSION you have only on server side):

```
<a href="page2.php?page=foo">Foo</a>
<a href="page2.php?page=bar">Bar</a>
```

page2.php

```
<?php

if ($_GET['page'] == 'foo') {
    $_SESSION['variable'] = "Foo";
} elseif ($_GET['page'] == 'bar') {
    $_SESSION['variable'] = "Bar";
}
```